# Using maxdepth and while in orientdb traversal

Tags: orientdb, orientdb-2.1

I am using orientdb v2.1.4
Is it possible to do an orientdb traversal from a target record with a while condition and a maxdepth parameter in either SQL or the Java API? For example:

```
traverse all() from TargetRecordID maxdepth 25 while @class <> 'some_edge_class'
```

The orientdb parser seems to apply the maxdepth condition and ignores the while condition.

I use the while condition because I have 10 different edge classes overall, but I wish to **do the traversal while excluding a subset (~3) of the edge classes**. If you have an alternative approach that I use to ignore certain edge classes during the traversal, that would be great as well.

Comment: this seems to be a bug, you should file an issue in the official issue tracker

Comment: The page at http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/SQL-Traverse.html indicates the given query is syntactically correct, so 2.1.7 (or at least the version I'm using) is clearly deficient.  A workaround that does seem to work, however, is to include a constraint on $depth in the WHILE condition (e.g. `WHILE ... and $depth <= 25`), instead of using MAXDEPTH.

Comment: @LuigiD thanks, will do

Comment: @peak Thanks for the feedback. I was using the approach you suggest,  but I recently read that maxdepth is faster than $depth, so I wanted to try using maxdepth with the while condition. And, as you said, it seems like it's syntactically correct, so, i figured i'd check if anybody has this issue.

Comment: @LuigiD Here it is: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5445

Comment: Here's a link to the OrientDB issue: https://github.com/orientechnologies/orientdb/issues/5445

Comment: @peak yup, i just made that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query:

```
traverse both() from YourClass while both('your_edge_class').size() = 0 and $depth <= 25
```

so the traverse won't pass on the vertices connected to the edge/edges that you specified

Edit:

Given the following graph example and assuming that you don't want the edges `type1` and `type2`, would you like to get the nodes 1,2,3,4,5 and 8 connected to the edge `type 3` or do you want to avoid all the vertices connected also with `type 1`and `type 2`?

[image]

Edit:

You can use this javascript function with three parameters (rid,maxDepth,excludeEdges)

```
var g=orient.getGraph();
var result=[];
var current=[];
var next=[];
var listEdges=excludeEdges.substring(1,excludeEdges.length-1).split(",");
var root=g.command('sql','select from '+rid);
current.push(root[0]);
var step=1;
while(current.length>0 && step<=maxDepth){
    for(i=0;i<current.length;i++){
        getVertex(current[i],"OUT");
        getVertex(current[i],"IN");
    }
    change();
    step++;
}
return result;

function change(){
    current=[];
    for (index=0;index<next.length;index++)
        current.push(next[index]);
    next=[];
}

function getVertex(start,direction){
    var edgeDir="outE()";
    var reverseDirection="in";
    if(direction=="IN"){
        edgeDir="inE()";
        reverseDirection="out";
    }
    var edges=g.command("sql","select expand("+edgeDir +") from "+start.getId());
    for(h=0;h<edges.length;h++){
        var found=false;
        for(m=0;m<listEdges.length;m++){
            if(edges[h].getProperty("@class")==listEdges[m]){
                found=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(found==false){
            var vertex=g.command("sql","select expand("+ reverseDirection + ") from " +edges[h].getId());
            for(j=0;j<result.length;j++){
                if(result[j].getId().toString().equals(vertex[0].getId().toString()) ||
                    vertex[0].getId().toString().equals(rid)){
                    found=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found==false){
                result.push(vertex[0]);
                next.push(vertex[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Using the following command

```
select expand(result) from (select myFunction("#9:1",25,"[type1,type2]") as result)
```

Comment: Hey @LucaS, thanks for the feedback. So, I realized i made a small mistake in my question. I want to traverse from a particular record (i'll edit this in my question). So, in your example above: Suppose vertex 2 has `RID #1:2`. I want to execute a traversal to depth 2 from #1:2 ignoring edges `type1` and `type2`, therefore returning vertices 1, 3, 5, 4. 

Do you think this query would do the trick on the graph in your example?

`traverse both() from #1:2 while both('type1').size() = 0 and both('type2').size() = 0 and $depth <= 2`

Comment: Hi kfresh, that query wouldn't work if a condition wasn't respected from the starting node. I found different ways to obtain the vertices you're looking for. 1) To find 1,3,4,5 you can use TRAVERSE with: `select expand($a) from #1:2
let $a=(traverse both('type3') from (select in('type3') from $parent.$current) while both('type3').size() > 0 and $depth < 2 and name <> $current.name)
order by name`

Comment: 2) Without TRAVERSE: `select expand($a) as node from #1:2
let $a=(select from node where both('type3').size() > 0 and name <> $parent.current.name)
unwind node`

Comment: Hi kfresh, have you got a chance to try the queries ?

Comment: Hey LucaS, thanks for the options. I didn't try it out, but i think I understand what you're doing in them and I can see how they would yield the desired result. But, I'm not sure how to rewrite this query (e.g. your first option) for my case, where I have ~10 edge types and i don't want to traverse 3 edge types, and the depth is <10. At least, from the perspective of writing the query, it seems like it'll be messy. WDYT?

Comment: Hi kfresh, I think it could it be possible to solve your problem with a javascript function instead of a query, could you accept it as an alternative ?

Answer (score 0):

With Java Api

```
OrientGraph g=new OrientGraph("remote:localhost/yourDb");
Traverse traverse = new Traverse(g);

List<String> listExcludeEdges=new ArrayList<String>();
listExcludeEdges.add("type1");
listExcludeEdges.add("type2");
int maxDepth=3;
String id="#9:1";

Set<Vertex> vertex=traverse.get(id,maxDepth,listExcludeEdges);
for(Vertex v:vertex){
    System.out.println(v.getId());
}
g.shutdown();
```

Class traverse

```
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Direction;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Edge;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex;
import com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientGraph;

public class Traverse {

    private Set<Vertex> listVertex = new LinkedHashSet<Vertex>(); 
    private OrientGraph g;
    private int maxDepth;
    private List<String> listExcludeEdges;
    private Vertex root;

    public Traverse(OrientGraph g) {
        this.g = g;
    }

    public Set<Vertex> get(String id,int maxDepth,List<String> listExcludeEdges) {
        this.maxDepth=maxDepth;
        this.listExcludeEdges=listExcludeEdges;
        if(checkClassOrRid(id)){
            if (getRoot(id)) 
                getChildren(1,this.root);
        }
        return this.listVertex;
    }

    private boolean checkClassOrRid(String id){
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^#[0-9]+:[0-9]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(id);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            for (Vertex v : g.getVertices()) {
                if (v.getId().toString().equals(id))
                    return true;
            }   
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected boolean getRoot(String id) {      
        this.root =  g.getVertex(id);
        if(this.root!=null)
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    protected void getChildren(int step,Vertex from) {
        if(step<=maxDepth){
            getVertex(Direction.OUT,from,step);
            getVertex(Direction.IN,from,step);
        }
    }

    private void getVertex(Direction direction,Vertex from,int step){
        Iterable<Edge> edges = from.getEdges(direction);
        for(Edge e:edges){
            boolean found=false;
            for(String s:this.listExcludeEdges){
                if(e.getProperty("@class").equals(s))
                    found=true;
            }
            if(found==false){
                Vertex vertex=null;
                if(direction==Direction.OUT)
                    vertex=e.getVertex(Direction.IN);
                else
                    vertex=e.getVertex(Direction.OUT);
                this.listVertex.add(vertex);
                getChildren(step+1,vertex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```